# Trying to get property of non-object in on line 20

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting an error and I don't really know where is the issue. Please can anybody show me what is wrong? I would appreciate any assistance, thanks!

```
Trying to get property of non-object in on line 20
```

class.php

```
class PostsData extends dbh {

    public function fetchAllPosts() {

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM post";
                $stmt = $this->connect()->query($sql);
                $stmt->execute([]);
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

                return $result;
        }   }
```

blog.php

```
$post_ = new PostsData;
$allposts = $post_->fetchAllPosts();


   foreach ($allposts as $post) {

    echo $post->post_title; //error
```

Comment: You don't need the square braces in your `execute()` call.

Comment: I would say there shouldn't be execute at all. Running your query twice makes a negative sense

Answer (score -2):

You are not checking if the result returned is null or not. The error would be generated if it is because there will be no property to access altogether.

Consider a print statement in FetchAllPosts function to check if you get any rows returned. That may help narrow down the scope of the error.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The reason there is never a property to access is because `fetchAll()` returns an array of arrays by default.